# Angular component with transcluded markup

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create an Angular component and transclude the inner HTML of the component, but the markup of the inner HTML does not seem to be compiling. My use case for this is that the component has an attribute binding that I want to use in multiple ways, so the template will never be exactly the same.

For example, say I have the following simple controller:

```
class ComponentCtrl {
    $onInit() {
        this.variable = 'hello world';
    }
}

let MyComponent = {
    controller: ComponentCtrl
};

app.component('myComponent', MyComponent);
```

I want the following HTML:

```
<my-component>
    <div style="color: green;">{{ $ctrl.variable }}</div>
</my-component>
<my-component>
    <div style="color: red;">{{ $ctrl.variable }}</div>
</my-component>
```

to render as:

```
<div style="color: green;">hello world</div>
<div style="color: red;">hello world</div>
```

However, right now it is only rendering as:

```
<div style="color: green;"></div>
<div style="color: red;"></div>
```

without the markup being evaluated.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it's angular 1 ou 2 ?

Comment: This is Angular 1 (version 1.5).

Comment: what you are attempting to do isn't currently possible with angular directives or components (possibly never will be possible).  Unfortunately, transcluded elements do not become part of the child scope of the element they are transcluded into.  in this case, `$ctrl` still refers to the controller above `my-component`, not `ComponentCtrl`.

Comment: you *might* be able to accomplish this by manually transcluding your elements (extracting the element's inner HTML, running `$compile` against it, then writing that output into the component template).  I've never tried to do this personally, however....

Comment: Ok... If not components then, can you please recommend what the appropriate way to accomplish what I'm trying to do is?

Answer (score 0):

did you write the right name of controller inside your `{{ }}` in html? you wrote `controller: ComponentCtrl` and then `{{ $ctrl.variable }}`. it looks like they must have the same names

Comment: I thought the controller name defaults to $ctrl, unless I defined a different name with the controllerAs property.

Answer (score 0):

Transclusion is not made by default, you have to especify on your component that it has to be transcluded. Also, you didn't especify on your template where it should be trasncluded. Therefore, your component should look like:

```
let MyComponent = {
    transclude: true, // tell angular to transclude it
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>', // tell where it will be transcluded
    controller: ComponentCtrl
};

app.component('myComponent', MyComponent);
```

However, how was told on comments, component scopes are always isolated. Therefore, ou won't be able to access `{{ $ctrl.variable }}` from outside the component.

Comment: I tried setting transclude as you suggested but my inner HTML markup is still not being evaluated. I made a jsFiddle here to demonstrate: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adrosenthal/ng43f688/2/)

Comment: That's because component scopes are always isolated. So you cannot access it from outside your component unless from bindings. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ng43f688/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from `{{ $ctrl.variable }}`. In fact $ctrl try to link with a parent controller not with the controller of your component.

If you want interact with the controller of your component you need to use some parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The transcluded content's scope has a $parent property that always points to the host component's scope.

So you could do something like this -

```
<my-component>
    <div style="color: green;">{{ $parent.$ctrl.variable }}</div>
</my-component>
<my-component>
    <div style="color: red;">{{ $parent.$ctrl.variable }}</div>
</my-component>
```

Plunk link that uses $parent property -  http://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckdwiuzlb00073b661a7blt3f/